# where is sh interpreter source code in AOSP?

Tags: android, c++, android-source

I want to know where is the corresponding source code to `/system/bin/sh` in Android AOSP 7.1, I found it in `/system/core/sh` in AOSP 4.4, but I can not find it in 5.0+.

Much Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been moved to external/mksh.

Check this reference:
http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/external/mksh/